# One To One Relationship With EF Code First - Foreign Keys Aren't Correct

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a 1 to 1 relationship between two entities where both ends are required.  They're basic entities, like this

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int? EntityAID {get; set;}
    public virtual EntityB EntityB {get; set;
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int? EntityBID {get; set;}
    public virtual EntityA EntityA {get; set;
}
```

I have an EntityTypeConfiguration object for EntityA that I use to configure the relationship.  I want entityA to be the principal in the relationship, which, if I understand this process correctly, means EntityB will have a foreign key to EntityA in its database table.  Here is my configuratoin statement

```
HasRequired(e=>e.EntityB).WithRequiredPrincipal(e=>e.EntityA);
```

I am updating my database with Code First Migration.  When I generate the migration that will setup this relationship, the migration is correctly identifying the fact it needs to put a foreign key on the table for EntityB, however it is creating the foreign key to the table for EntityA with the primary key for EntityB, like this:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.TableForEntityB", t => t.EntityBID)
```

It should be using the ID for EntityA as the foreign key.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  I'm stumped.  I've tried using WithRequiredDependent, and all that does is create an identical situation on TableForEntityA.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't have both ends be required, this isn't even an EF restriction it's a database restriction. One of your entities is always going to have to be the parent entity (i.e., inserted first). Based on this maybe you can update your question and get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stemmed from my misunderstanding of the one to one relationship as implemented by EF.  I read up and found out that EF used a shared primary key relationship when making one to one relatoinships.  So I changed EntityB to look like this:

```
public class EntityB
{
    public int? EntityAID {get; set;}
    public virtual EntityA EntityA {get; set;
}
```

And then configured the relationship like this:

HasRequired(c => c.EntityA).WithRequiredDependent(p => p.EntityB);

when configuring EntityB.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing guess work here but I think the foreign key being created is not on primary key for `EntityB` table as well. `EntityBID` in the `EntityB` class is not the primary key for `EntityB` obviously because you are specifying it as a `Nullable` type, so what is it?